# The remainder when a polynomial, $f(x)$ is divided by $x-1$ is the same as the quotient. Find the value of $f(0)$

Tags: polynomials, rational-functions

The remainder when a polynomial, $f(x)$ is divided by $x-1$ is the same as the quotient. Find the value of $f(0)$.

So I've assumed the remainder but be a linear expression and so must the quotient meaning that $f(x)$ must be a quadratic function?

So if $f(x)$ is a quadratic then  $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

$$\frac{f(x)}{x-1}=(ax+b+a) + \frac{r}{x-1}$$

But I am unsure where to go from here? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $f(x) \,=\, \color{#c00}{q(x)}(x-1) + r\, $ and $\,\color{#c00}{q(x) = r}\,\Rightarrow\,f(x) =\ \ldots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remainder is the same as the quotient, so the quotient is a *constant*. This implies $f$ is *linear* – write it as $ax+b$. Then
$$ax+b=a(x-1)+a+b$$
$$a+b=a\qquad b=0$$
Thus $f(x)=ax$ for some real $a$. Regardless of the choice, $f(0)=0$.